# About working of op-amp and making a potentiostat

Tags: inverting-amplifier

I am trying to make a potentiostat for cyclic voltametry of molecules, using op-amps, an Arduino board, and LabVIEW program.

Here is the circuit, from a [paper from the *Journal of Chemical Education.*](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/suppl/10.1021/acs.jchemed.8b00340/suppl_file/ed8b00340_si_002.pdf)

[*An Easily Fabricated Low-Cost Potentiostat Coupled with User-Friendly Software for Introducing Students to Electrochemical Reactions and Electroanalytical Techniques*](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jchemed.8b00340)

[image]

I am not getting the desired data out of it.

I checked the op-amp (UA741CP) to make a  simple inverting amplifier, with Vcc = 15V, -Vcc = 0V, and tried using different resistors (say, Rf= 10k, Rin =1k.) V1 =5V and V2 connected to ground.

I am getting input and output voltage nearly the same. I should get an amplified voltage, right?

Are my op-amps not working properly?

I do not have an electronics background.

Comment: Please [edit] and add the link to the paper of journel of chemical education

Comment: Check potentiostat circuits from sensor vendors (Alphasense, TE and others) and from Analog Devices. They don't use the 741.  Those circuits are extremely sensitive, so you will have to make sure your work area is ESD safe.

Comment: @Amju Did you find a resolution to this issue? I am also trying to design and fabricate a potentiostat. Looking for advice on op-amps to use.

Answer (score 2):

The quad op-amp is specified to be an LMC6484, which is a RRIO (rail-to-rail input/output) CMOS op-amp that will operate very well from a 3-15V supply (a single 5V supply is used in the design).

A cluster of \$\mu\$A741s is not really a viable substitute, but you might get something usable if you add a negative supply of at least -5V, however it's also much more likely to **damage** your Arduino board since voltages below 0V and above 5V will be present in the circuit, so I strongly suggest getting the specified quad op-amp or something very similar.

[image]